# rails/Heroku: custom fonts working in local but not on Heroku

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, fonts

I have a problem with my custom fonts on Rails 4.

I put the fonts in /vendor/assets/fonts/ directory, and in my application.rb, I added:

```
config.assets.paths << "#{Rails}/vendor/assets/fonts"
config.assets.precompile << /\.(?:svg|eot|woff|ttf)$/
```

In addition, in my production.rb config file, I have:

```
config.serve_static_assets = true
```

I'm using sass so in my css, I added:

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Raleway-Thin'
  src: url('Raleway-Thin.ttf')

....
font-family: "Raleway-Thin", sans-serif
```

In my application.css, I also added because i'm using font-awesome:

```
 *= require font-awesome.min
```

I'm pushing on Heroku, and my fonts are ot loaded, it's not working...

Do you have any ideas what's the problem please, (or if there is any command to type before/after pushing)?

Thanks by advance

Comment: Are you getting 404's in the browser?  That is, does the browser *try* to load the font files and say "can't find them"?

Comment: Are your fonts and your rails app are served from same domain? Because if you use AmazonS3 or CloudFront for assets you should configure CORS in amazon console

Comment: I have an app that is successfully running on heroku and serving up fonts.  We have this `config.serve_static_assets = false` in our production config and things are working for us.  Is there a reason you want Rails to serve your static assets (not thin or unicorn)?

Comment: No my fonts are include in the project in vendor directory. And I get the page, just not with the fonts .. and font awesome replace my font by squares ...

Comment: So does your browser show (in the network call list) that it's looking for the font file?  and not finding it (404)?

Comment: mr rogers, I tried that too, there is no difference ... I did it cause I found some answers about that but didnt work for me.

Comment: sorry, yes in my browser console, I get the error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) -http://application.herokuapp.com/assets/Raleway-Thin.ttf

Comment: And did you check on the heroku filesystem to verify that the font file is there?  Try `heroku run bash` then `ls public/assets`.  If it's not there, then it's not getting precompiled.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46971/discussion-between-mr-rogers-and-guillaumek)

Comment: No, unfortunatly, there is something, the precompiled file: Raleway-Thin-3386cdbc197d5b8a83a45011cae76b25.ttf
Raleway-Thin-e0996c5757ebe8e2f22b6d0f3a19eda7.ttf

Comment: well... i'm at a loss.  did you try changing the serve_static_assets to false?  I don't know why you'd want rails to serve up static assets when unicorn or thin will do it just fine.

Comment: Yes I know, I changed it to false again, just tried it in case of .. Cause i'm lost too, tried many solution who doesn't work. Do I have to do anything in console before pushin heroku ?

Comment: i don't think so.  You might try running the whole thing on your dev box in production mode `RAILS_ENV=production rails s`.  You'll probably have to muck with the db config so that everything is happy, but maybe that would illuminate what's happening.  The last difference i can see from what we did is that we specified the compile path a bit differently `config.assets.precompile += %w(.svg .eot .woff .ttf)` but i can't imagine that your syntax would be causing trouble.  You might also try asset-url() instead of font-url() helper but they're probably doing the same thing.

Comment: no same errors on the last try .. :S do you think it could be from i changed the database from mysql2 to pg for heroku ? I dont think so at all, but i have no idea, i think I tried anything so ...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the helper function and utilize the Rails asset pipeline?

```
@font-face
  font-family: 'Raleway-Thin'
  src: font-url('Raleway-Thin.ttf')
```

Comment: This looks like the right answer.  You could alternatively try `url('/assets/Raleway-Thin.ttf')` which should be what the font-url method gives you (except possibly with a digest).

Comment: No it doesn't change too. I forgot to mention that I have in my Gemfie: gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production

Comment: Because you're using Rails 4.  I think that the assets that get built using the asset pipeline all have the digest extension.  Which would mean url('Raleway.ttf') won't match because the file is probably called Raleway-Thin-4444e3cae9b52ca.ttf (or similar).  That's why it feels like the font-url helper should help out.  When that's in place, does the font file request from the browser have the digest in the filename?

Comment: i;m not sure to understand, with the font-url helper, I get the same error : Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)

Answer (score 0):

You can import font into folder assest/stylesheet/font and run `bundle exec rake assets:precompile` before deploy to heroku. I has tried and it's work. In addition, I have search font name that you have used, so I recommended you can using Google Web Font for this font: http://www.google.com/fonts#UsePlace:use/Collection:Raleway

Comment: Could be a solution but I have some other font I need to include in my project ..